# does WriteFile post a completion packet on finishing immediately when using io completion ports

Tags: asynchronous, winapi, writefile, iocp

I know that when WSARecv is used with it may finishes immediately and in such case a completion packet will still be posted and this behavior can be altered using SetFileCompletionNotificationModes

but I want to know the case for files and pipes with WriteFile , if I used iocp to make async reads and writes and an operation has finished immediately will the same behavior take place ? or I have to handle this ?

Comment: no any difference between `WSARecv` or `WriteFile` here. both is asynchronous i/o api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exist common behavior for all asynchronous api, it implicit described in  [CancelThreadpoolIo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-cancelthreadpoolio) function

note, by design we need call [CancelThreadpoolIo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-cancelthreadpoolio)  when and only when will not notify to the I/O completion port and the associated I/O callback function will not be called.

> you must call the `CancelThreadpoolIo` function for either of the
>   following scenarios:
>
> - An overlapped (asynchronous) I/O operation fails (that is, the    asynchronous I/O function call returns failure with an error code
>     other than `ERROR_IO_PENDING`).
> - An asynchronous I/O operation returns immediately with success and    the file handle associated with the I/O completion object has the
>     notification mode `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS`. The file
>     handle will not notify the I/O completion port and the associated I/O 
>     callback function will not be called.

so let `dwErrorCode` error code returned by api (`NOERROR` if win32 api return TRUE)

the next function say you - will be or not notify to IOCP

```
bool IsWillBeNotification(ULONG dwErrorCode, BOOL bSkipCompletionPortMode)
{
    switch (dwErrorCode)
    {
    case ERROR_IO_PENDING:
        return true;
    case NOERROR:
        return !bSkipCompletionPortMode;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

in case we use native API and NTSTATUS

```
bool IsWillBeNotification(NTSTATUS status, BOOL bSkipCompletionPortMode)
{
    return (status == STATUS_PENDING) || (!NT_ERROR(status) && !bSkipCompletionPortMode);
}
```

so:

- if `STATUS_PENDING` - will be IOCP packet
- if `NT_ERROR(status)` - will be no packet (status in range `[0xC0000000,
  0xFFFFFFFF]` )
- otherwise based on *bSkipCompletionPortMode* - will be if it not set

note that this is general rule for any asynchronous io api. only `NtLockFile`/`LockFileEx` - exception from this rule - can be IOCP notification even if api just fail, due to error inside `NtLockFile` implementation

Answer (score 2):

Per [Why does my asynchronous I/O request return TRUE instead of failing with ERROR_IO_PENDING?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101008-00/?p=12583):

> When you specify FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, you’re promising that your program knows how to handle I/O which completes asynchronously, but it does not require the I/O stack to behave asynchronously. A driver can choose to perform your I/O synchronously anyway. For example, if the write operation can be performed by writing to cache without blocking, the driver will just copy the data to the cache and indicate synchronous completion. Don’t worry, be happy: Your I/O completed even faster than you expected!
>
> **Even though the I/O completed synchronously, all the asynchronous completion notification machinery is still active. It’s just that they all accomplished their job before the Write­File call returned. This means that the event handle will still be signaled, the completion routine will still run (once you wait alertably), and if the handle is bound to an I/O completion port, the I/O completion port will receive a completion notification.**
>
> You can use the Set­File­Completion­Notification­Modes function to change some aspects of this behavior, giving some control of the behavior of the I/O subsystem when a potentially-asynchronous I/O request completes synchronously.

Comment: thanks . This includes all asynchronous apis including ConnectNamedPipe , right ?

Comment: I mean if ConnectNamedPipe  returned FALSE and GetLastError() returned ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED will a completion notification be posted ?

Comment: @dev65 - yes, will be. this related to **any** asynchronous api on file binded to some iocp in case we pass not zero pointer to context

Comment: @Remy but from the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-server-using-overlapped-i-o they signal an event when ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED is returned

Comment: @dev65 per that example: "*The state of the event object is not changed if the operation finishes before the function returns.*" - I don't know if that is true or not, I don't use Overlapped I/O very often. Seems to contradict what Raymond says. So you will just have to try it for yourself and see what really happens.

Comment: @dev65 - *I mean if ConnectNamedPipe returned FALSE and GetLastError() returned ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED will a completion notification be posted ?* - in this case will be no notification. notification will be if api return pending status or success status. in case error status - will be not

Comment: @RbMm I have already tried it : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94bdd003-a10a-4d6e-9221-514794f01ab7/will-i-receive-iocp-notification-from-connectnamedpipe-when-it-returns-0-and-getlasterror-returns?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Comment: @dev65 - exist general rule for all asynchronous I/O api. i know this topic very well. if api call return error status - so call completed synchronous with error - no packet will be queued to iocp. this is not about concrete api and status. this is for all

Comment: @dev65 - if want general knowledge - https://pastebin.com/HGD4BrHM

Comment: @RbMm that seems to be in direct conflict with what Raymond Chen wrote, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - what you more concrete mean under conflict ? the Raymond Chen not wrote about when notification will be and not. nothing say about error case. however i perfect know this topic. if error from I/O manager (due invalid arguments/handles, align, insuffient resourses) - no notification. otherwise request will be sent to driver. if driver return `NT_ERROR` code ( [c0000000, FFFFFFFF) range) will be no notification, otherwise will be (`Set­File­Completion­Notification­Modes` can prevent on synchronous success completion post notification)

Comment: but even in case error status can be completion notifications (if fast io used, it return true with error status). only correct solution which i know - need check iosb (overlapped) after I/O completed synchronous - are it modified. notification will be when and only when iosb modified. but because iosb can be accessed in concurrent from 2 threads (after api call and from callback) - need use reference count on it, for correct deletion. example when will be notification on error - call `LockFileEx` on folder (here fast io lock used, folder is invalid for lock).

Comment: and documentation everywhere wrong for this question - [SetFileCompletionNotificationModes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfilecompletionnotificationmodes)
*A request returns **success** immediately without returning ERROR_PENDING* - here **success** unnecessary word.

Comment: [CancelThreadpoolIo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-cancelthreadpoolio)
*An overlapped (asynchronous) I/O operation fails (that is, the asynchronous I/O function call returns failure with an error code other than ERROR_IO_PENDING).*
again exist rarely case I/O fail but will be notification, as in case `LockFileEx`- so not need call `CancelThreadpoolIo` in this case. simply demo - https://pastebin.com/qWrMYvy4 . may be even Raymond Chen dont know this, but i not sure that this topic interesting for somebody